# Angular 2 live site different to npm start site

Tags: node.js, angular

Currently my live site and production site (the one where you get an ip and port) look different for some reason. Is there any reason why? Is there a setting I somehow missed? It was matching the production site until yesterday.

If there's any code you need, let me know.

Comment: Have you checked the console for errors?

Comment: @Derek Both the npm start console and the firebug console give me no tangible error. Even if I just browse into the files say /app/app.component.ts It will show the current ts file but it keeps loading a non-existent, previous ts file :S

Answer (score 3):

Try to clear your cache, I have had sites in angular 2 that have not updated, and as soon as I clear my cache

Comment: Okay, that worked, but do I have to clear cache every time I want to view the update?

Comment: I think the main thing was I have to npm start the thing again. Still unsure, but clearing cache helped a bit I think.

Comment: You can disable the cache completely in chrome whilst the dev tools are open